# How to test the exit status from IPC::Run3

Tags: perl, exit-code, perl-ipc-run

I'm trying to test the Perl module IPC::Run3 but having difficulty in checking whether a command is failed or successful.
I know that IPC::Run3 issues an exit code if something is wrong with its arguments, but what about if the arguments are ok but the command does not exist? How can I test the following example?

Having a subroutine to call Run3

```
sub runRun3 {

    my $cmd = shift;
    my ($stdout, $stderr);

    run3($cmd, \undef, \$stdout, \$stderr);

#   if( $? == -1 ) {
    if (! $stdout and ! $stderr) {
        die "Something is wrong";
    } else {
        print "OK \n";
    }

}
```

when command `$cmds[0]` below is executed (the `ls` command of *nix systems) it prints `OK` as expected, but with command `$cmds[1]` it just says `No such file or directory at ./testrun3.pl line 18`.
With a test to the exit code I want it to print `Something is wrong` instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use IPC::Run3;

my @cmds = qw(ls silly);

runRun3($cmds[0]);
runRun3($cmds[1]);
```

Or what would be the best alternative to IPC::Run3 in cases like this? This is just an oversimplification of the process, but eventually I would like to capture STDERR and STDOUT for more complex situations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points to go through.

First, for the direct question, the [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm) documentation tells us that

> `run3` throws an exception if the wrapped `system` call returned `-1` or anything went wrong with `run3`'s processing of filehandles. Otherwise it returns true. It leaves `$?` intact for inspection of exit and wait status.

The error you ask about is of that kind and you need to [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) the call to catch that exception

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my ($stdout, $stderr);

my @cmd = ("ls", "-l");

eval { run3 \@cmd, \undef, \$stdout, \$stderr };
if    ( $@        ) { print "Error: $@";                     }
elsif ( $? & 0x7F ) { say "Killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F ); }
elsif ( $? >> 8   ) { say "Exited with error ".( $? >> 8 );  }
else                { say "Completed successfully";          }
```

You can now print your own messages inside `if ($@) { }` block, when errors happen where the underlying [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) fails to execute. Such as when a non-existing program is called.

Here `$@` relates to `eval` while `$?` to `system`. So if `run3` didn't have a problem and `$@` is false next we check the status of `system` itself, thus `$?`. From docs

> Note that a true return value from `run3` doesn't mean that the command
>   had a successful exit code. Hence you should always check `$?`.

For variables `$@` and `$?` see [General Variables in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables), and `system` and `eval` pages.

A minimal version of this is to drop `eval` (and `$@` check) and expect the program to `die` if `run3` had problems, what should be rare, and to check (and print) the value of `$?`.

A note on `run3` interface. With `\@cmd` it expects `@cmd` to contain a command broken into words, the first element being the program and the rest arguments. There is a difference between writing a command in a string, supported by `$cmd` interface, and in an array.  See [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for explanation.

Which alternative would suit you best depends on your exact needs. Here are some options. Perhaps first   try [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/IPC-System-Simple-1.25/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm) (but no `STDERR` on the platter). For cleanly capturing all kinds of output [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Capture-Tiny-0.44/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm) is great.  On the other end there is [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.94/lib/IPC/Run.pm) for far more power.

Comment: @ikegami Oh, sure, much better to show it all (and correctly). Thank you.